# Среда Eclipse. Программирование под андроид

Tags: android, java, книги

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, дельную книгу, сайт, статью по обработке изображений на андроид.

Comment: Что подразумевается под "обработкой"?

Comment: Если подразумевается создание программы а-ля Paint.NET под Андроид, то бредовая идея искать книгу конкретно по обработке изображений под эту ось (да и скорее всего такой книги не существует, по крайней мере хорошей). Ищите общую литературу по этому вопросу, а только потом применяйте полученные знания под конкретную платформу.